# How can I get unzipped file data from libarchive.js

Tags: webassembly

```
import {Archive} from 'libarchive.js/main.js';

Archive.init({
    workerUrl: '/libarchive.js/dist/worker-bundle.js'
});

document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', async (e) => {
    const file = e.currentTarget.files[0];

    const archive = await Archive.open(file);
    archive.extractFiles(entry => {
        // { file: {File}, path: {String} }
        console.log('entry', entry);
    });
});
```

I got entry data that contained file information.
[image]

But it contains only file name, size, date, etc.
How can I get unzipped file data from the entry data?
I red github site(https://github.com/nika-begiashvili/libarchivejs), but I can't find the way.

Answer (score 0):

I can get file data using this code.

```
archive.extractFiles((entry) => { 
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(entry.file);
    
    reader.onload = function() {
        console.log('file data', reader.result);
    };
});
```